# Force a new database name on import with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, database, import

I have a large database dump.sql file I am importing from the command line in linux. The .sql dump creates a database named "database_name". I want to import the database from this .sql file but I want to force it to a database with a different name, as the script currently overwrites "database_name" and "database_name" already exists and has data I can't overwrite.

Is the best option to find and replace within the .sql file?  What is the best method for that since the file is 50mb.  I can't simply file_get_contents() on that shiz?  Can I?

Below are the lines I would have to replace in the .sql file:

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `database_name` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `database_name`;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to replace the database_name in the .sql file.

You can do that from the shell with `sed 's/database_name/new_database_name/' dumpFile.sql > newDumpFile.sql`

**this is the correct answer to my question but was provided by 'fab' in the comments of another answer.**

**NOTE**: As @Diego pointed out in the comments, if the string 'database_name' shows up anywhere else in this .sql dump, it will be replaced there as well. You may want to view the contents of the .sql file using `less file_name.sql` and then be more explicit with your find/replace.

Comment: saved me from opening 500 mb sql dump file!!

Comment: Handle with care because that expression will change every string "database_name" to "new_database_name".

Answer (score 9):

When dumping the database with `mysqldump`, use the option `--no-create-db`. This will suspress the `CREATE DATABASE` statement in your dump file.
Then restore the database with
`mysql -h <host> -u <user> -p <databaseName> < dump.sql`
In this way you can restore your data in whatever database you like (But that database has to exist!)

Comment: This is old data and only exists in this .sql dump.  I'm stuck with the CREATE DATABASE call in the .sql file.  (good solution otherwise)

Comment: In this case case you have to replace the `database_name` (As you mentioned already). You can do that with `sed 's/\`database_name\`/\`new_database_name\`/' dumpFile.sql > newDumpFile.sql`

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way is to open the file, find the following line (about 10 to 15 lines from start):

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `old_database_name` ...

USE `old_database_name`;

and replace old_database_name with the new name in both places. I just did this on a 5.9 GB file with vim. It took about 15 sec. to open the file, 3 sec. to edit the line and 30 sec. to save the file. Not sure any other text editor allows you do do this!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I was faced with the exact same problem today. Here is how I solved it:

```
pv 20171212.dump.bz2 | bunzip2 | sed -e '/^\(CREATE DATABASE\|USE\|.*DROP DATABASE\).*`<old db name>`/d' | mysql <new db name>
```

pv is just there to show a progress bar. The line could have been written as

```
bunzip2 20171212.dump.bz2 | sed -e '/^\(CREATE DATABASE\|USE\|.*DROP DATABASE\).*`<old db name>`/d' | mysql <new db name>
```

sed removes the lines preventing the database name change without altering any  text occurring into the dump file.